# Is there a way to have the links underlined by default with tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I just discovered tailwind css and I love it. But by default all the links have no style, meaning they are not underlined.

I would like to apply if possible a `text-decoration: underline` or simply the tailwind `.underline` class by default to all my links. I think it's a good practice to have them underlined for the web accessibility and I guess it's not very efficient to add the `.undeline` class to all my links.

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a base style for your elements in your Styles Sheet

```css
@layer base {
  a {
     @apply underline;
  }
}
```

[Adding Base Styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles#app)

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot :). I see they have other examples of adding its own base style here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#extending-preflight. I guess it's the `a { text-decoration: inherit }` in their base css that removes the underlines.

Comment: If that's it, why not accept the answer? :)